# In a list of string, how to remove string which are part of other string in the list?

Tags: python

In a list of string, how to remove string which are part of other string in the list?

Here is an example.

```
lst = ['Hello World', 'Hello', 'This is test', 'is test']
```

I would like to only get `['Hello World', 'This is test']` as the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply `list comprehension` in order to *filter* list.

Also, use `filter` method by applying a `lambda` *expression* as argument.

```
lst = ['Hello World', 'Hello', 'This is test', 'is test']
lst = [string for string in lst if len(list(filter(lambda x: string in x, lst))) == 1]
```

Output

```
['Hello World', 'This is test']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `any`:

```
lst = ['Hello World', 'Hello', 'This is test', 'is test']
new_results = [a for i, a in enumerate(lst) if any(h in a and c != i for c, h in enumerate(lst))]
```

Output:

```
['Hello World', 'This is test']
```